# Apollo-Client - Long query plus short query vs. one query to rule them all, which one makes more sense memory-wise?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

My user query is getting longer and longer, and I was thinking about separating it into two queries, a `ME_QUERY` which has the most used params like userType, userName, userID, and a `USER_QUERY` to contain all of the params I need for the user, but the `USER_QUERY` will only be needed in the user settings and the payment page, while the `ME_QUERY` is used in almost every component due to the fact that I need the `userType` everywhere for `ACL`.

But I am not sure if it's a good idea to separate them into two queries, since they are both cached in their own space in the memory, so separating them means two place in the memory, while having a long query, will be long, but will only reserve one place in the memory and updating it after mutations would also be easier.

So the question is, do I need the `ME_QUERY` too or the `USER_QUERY` which already ran once after user logged in would be sufficient?

The following are the two queries:

```
export const USER_QUERY = gql`
    query {
        user {
            uid
            avatar
            isAdmin
            projectCount
            sessions
            providers
            payments // is a long object itself
            coupon
            credits
            email
            userName
            userType
            createdAt
            hasPassword
            companyName
            vatNumber
            addressLine1
            addressLine2
            country
            companySize
        }
    }
`;
```

```
export const ME_QUERY = gql`
    query {
        user {
            uid
            avatar
            isAdmin
            email
            userName
            userType
            createdAt
        }
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: There is certainly a benefit to query splitting, but it lies in the improved experience for your users and can only be achieved with a properly-configured InMemoryCache.

Query results in Apollo are normalized:

> The InMemoryCache normalizes your data before saving it to the store by splitting the result into individual objects, creating a unique identifier for each object, and storing those objects in a flattened data structure. By default, InMemoryCache will attempt to use the commonly found primary keys of id and _id for the unique identifier if they exist along with __typename on an object.

If you're not seeing this behavior with your user query, it's likely because your id field is called `uid` and not `id` or `_id`. You'll need to implement a custom dataIdFromObject function [as outlined in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#configuration):

```
import { InMemoryCache, defaultDataIdFromObject } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  dataIdFromObject: object => {
    switch (object.__typename) {
      // or whatever your user type is called
      case 'User': return `${object.__typename}:${object.uid}`
      // other types here that don't have an id or _id 
      default: return defaultDataIdFromObject(object)
    }
  }
})
```

Having a correctly configured cache means two things in the context of your question:

- Queries that fetch an object with the same cache key will have their results merged.
- Mutations that return an object matching an existing cache key will automatically update that object.

This means you can split up your `user` query and request a minimal amount of fields to initially load your page and delay requesting the rest of your fields until the user navigates to a page where those fields are needed. You can even use [prefetching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/performance.html#prefetching) to get the second query ahead of time.

Additionally, if you have a mutation that updates a user, as long as the mutation returns an object that has a matching cache key (i.e. in this case, it includes a `guid`), it will automatically update the cache for that object. There's no need to refetch queries or manually update the store in these cases -- Apollo will handle it all for you.

Side note: lists of objects in the cache are unaffected by the above. If a mutation results in something needing to be added or removed from a list, there's no way for Apollo to infer which lists are impacted. In these cases, you would [update the cache yourself](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#after-mutations).

Query splitting can make your app faster and improve your users' experience, but should have no impact on the amount of memory or the difficulty of updating your cache after a mutation because of the way caching works in Apollo.